# Detecting arithmetic overflow in C

Tags: c, security, debugging

1. As the title suggests, is there a way in C to detect such errors? For example if I try a complex computation like `int a=b*c+d*e/f;` can I detect if the result has gone beyond the range of `int`?
2. Suppose I decide that handling such errors comes at a cost of performance hit, what are the security implications and what at worst could happen? Can a malware author exploit this bug?

Comment: 1) No. 2) Yes, and also it doesn't really make sense to ask about the behaviour of undefined behaviour. You can make a correct program fast, but it's very hard to make a fast program correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c

Comment: @KerrekSB So do you actually mean to say I'm helpless if I wanted to make a program that's "arithmetic overflow"-proof? I mean I'm ready to do anything to make the program robust.

Comment: You can always test for **potential** overflow. The problem is how much overhead/additional complexity (source code and runtime) you can accept.

Comment: Q2: if it can overflow, your code will probably break before any malware can take advantage anyway.

Comment: @MayankVerma: You're not helpless at all. It's entirely possible to check the values *before* computing an expression. It has a runtime cost, of course, but there's no debate whether you should do it. The program simply doesn't make sense if you don't.

Comment: Define your own safe_add, safe_mul, etc. functions. Return, say, INT_MIN if any overflow occurred (or if either argument was INT_MIN already). At the end of the calculation, check if your answer was INT_MIN - if so, an overflow occurred.

Answer (score 1):

In the simpler case of `unsigned int` you can test for overflow *before* the multiplication like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void multiply(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    if(UINT_MAX / a >= b)
        printf("%u * %u = %u\n", a, b, a * b);
    else
        printf("%u * %u is out of range\n", a, b);
}

int main(void)
{
    multiply(70000, 60000);
    multiply(70000, 80000);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
70000 * 60000 = 4200000000
70000 * 80000 is out of range
```

And you can employ more extensive tests for `int`

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, the answer to your first question is no. You can do checks for simple operations, but for larger ones the checks quickly become arduous. Datatypes and primitives like an `int` are only defined to be able to handle a finite range of values. If you're worried about overflow, the simple answer is use a bigger datatype (i.e. `int64_t`, etc.).

To answer your latter question, it depends on context. If a space shuttle's navigation software encountered an overflow in the right part of it's calculations, it could change course erratically and crash. What I'm getting at is that technically anything can happen and it's very hard to be "completely" safe. Hedge your bets and make sure don't have overflow by using properly sized datatypes. It helps to find bounds on possible input values and use those as a guide, but if bounds aren't really applicable you can just use the largest types available. `uint64_t` can handle positive integers up to 1.8446744e+19 ... which is huge.